# pod install mkdir Permission denied

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have a new React Native project with RN 64.0, when I run `npx pod install` it fail returning this:

```
npx: installed 1 in 27.036s
Scanning for pods...
1.10.1
> pod install
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `MyMALnew`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.64.0)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.64.0)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
mkdir -p /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/MyMALnew/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec && touch /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/MyMALnew/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/MyMALnew/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm

mkdir: /Volumes/Macintosh: Permission denied
```

ps: this is the first time I use npx prefix with RN, not sure if this is the issue here :)

Thanx for helping..

Comment: Did you find any solution to this. I guess the problem is with spaces in folder names.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal renaming volume name worked for me

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/rename-disk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your Volume name "Macintosh HD" consists of two words separated by space.

This generated path -> **mkdir -p /Volumes/Macintosh HD** should be replaced with **mkdir -p "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"** (added quotation marks) by RN team I think.

**I had the same issue and renaming of my Volume to single word and reinstalling node_modules solved the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Running your `pod install` command using `sudo`.
Or Update your project directory permissions using `chmod` command.

Comment: Using `sudo` return `You cannot run CocoaPods as root`, `chmod` on root doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This so happens because Cocoapods is not able to create / modify files in your project. The suggested option above - `sudo pod install` will never work, as Cocoapods is not allowed to be run as root.

The best solution would be to enable Read and Write access for the folder inside which you are trying to run the command. Go to finder, right click on the folder and enable the access, then it should run fine.